# 64 assembly language using nasm on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I am trying to write a simple hello world program in 64-bit assembly and run on Ubuntu 64 bit.  The program is as follows :

```
global _start           ; entry point export for ld section .text   
_start:     ; system call to write message to stdout
    mov rax, 1      ; sys_write
    mov rdi, 1      ; stdout
    mov rsi, mes    ; message address
    mov rdx, len    ; message length
    syscall     ; exit sys call
    mov rax, 60     ; exit call id
    mov rdi, 0      ; return success
    syscall
section .data
    mes: db 'Hello, world!',0x0A    ; message
    len :   equ $-mes
```

I assembled it using  `nasm -f elf64 hello64.asm`
and tried linking it using `ld -o hello64 hello64.o`
it gives me following error -

> ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `hello64.o' is incompatible
>   with i386 output

I get same error even when using flags --oformat elf64-x86-64 or elf64-little or elf64-big.

can someone help out ?

Comment: related: [building static / dynamic binaries from asm with GNU tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain).  `_start` or `main`, with/without libc.  Possibly you're using a 32-bit install of Ubuntu?  Try `file /usr/bin/ld`, although I'd actually expect a 32-bit `ld` to be able to make 64-bit executables with the right `--oformat`.

Answer (score 3):

The following works on my system:

```
nasm -f elf64 hello64.asm
ld -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o hello64 hello64.o
```

Comment: Do you have ia32-libs package installed?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider running `apt-get update` again. I'm running it on an updated version `15.04` and it's working for me.